# Setting menu items based on user input android

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I have been reading answers to questions on here for hours and no solutions seem to work for me.

I am creating an android app for DnD Character Creations, and if the user selects a magical class, I would like to add a spell book option to the main menu.

For some reason, no matter what I do, it will either show visible or invisible based on the XML and will not change it through the code.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--TODO: create related icons-->

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:title="Profile"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_battle"
        android:title="Battle"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_items"
        android:title="Items"
        android:visible="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_spellbook"
        android:title="Spell Book"
        android:visible="false"/>
</group>
```

This was attempt 1 in java:

```
public void classBasedTraits() {

    int intHealthInitial = 0;


    //end attempt
    switch (strCharacterClass) {
        case "Sorcerer":
        case "Wizard":
            intHealthInitial = 6; //  Sorcerer and Wizard's initial health is 6
            break;
        case "Bard":
        case "Cleric":
        case "Druid":
        case "Monk":
        case "Rogue":
        case "Warlock":
            intHealthInitial = 8; //  Bard, Cleric, Druid, Monk, Rogue, and Warlock's initial health is 8
            break;
        case "Fighter":
        case "Paladin":
        case "Ranger":
            intHealthInitial = 10; //  Fighter, Paladin, and Ranger's initial health is 10
            break;
        case "Barbarian":
            intHealthInitial = 12; //  Barbarian's initial health is 12
            break;
    }

    //Attempt to create spellbook for magical classes'

    Set<String> setMagical;
    setMagical = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Bard", "Cleric", "Druid", "Paladin",
            "Ranger", "Sorcerer", "Warlock", "Wizard"));

    if(setMagical.contains(strCharacterClass)){
        magical = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    intTotalHP = intHealthInitial + intConstitutionMod; // Starting HP is initial health + constitution modifier
    intRemainingHP = intTotalHP; // Sets character at full health
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.nav_spellbook).setVisible(magical);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

this was attempt 2 in java, in the Profile activity class, because this class is called after the character class has been specified, and this function is when the menu is set up for the first time:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
    Set<String> setMagical;
    setMagical = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Bard", "Cleric", "Druid", "Paladin",
            "Ranger", "Sorcerer", "Warlock", "Wizard"));
    MenuItem spellbook = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_spellbook);

    if(setMagical.contains(characterClass))
    {

        spellbook.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        spellbook.setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the project on github if anyone want's to take a look at the full code
https://github.com/Doszust/RPG-Character-Sheet/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/ucfknights/dylan_oszust/dungeonsanddragons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with the first attempt. You use `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to trigger a call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` where you implement your changes to the menu.

You need to return `true` from `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in order for it to be displayed.

Also don't inflate the menu again in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. You are already supplied the `menu` in the method parameters.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);    

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.findItem(R.id.nav_spellbook).setVisible(magical);

    return true;
}
```

Your menu file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:visible="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_battle"
            android:title="Battle"
            android:visible="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_items"
            android:title="Items"
            android:visible="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_spellbook"
            android:title="Spell Book"
            android:visible="false"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

So `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is where you first create the menu. Then `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is where you can modifiy it from then on.

Comment: The reason I inflated it was because it was returning null pointer for the menu item.  I have also tried returning true as well as super.  The menu item is still missing even though magical = true.

Comment: I've noticed the menu you're inflating is called `activity_main_drawer`, and your xml does not have the root element <menu></menu>. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` & `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` are for the Activity's standard options menu (i.e. the "3 dots" dropdown menu) . They are not for a drawer menu. What I have written in my answer above, is the correct way to do it for the Activity's standard options menu.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation to see what the correct xml for checkable menu items should look like. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable

Comment: I have the open and close menu tags, I don't know why they didn't paste in the post, but they're in the code.

Comment: However, thank you for noting that those methods are for the standard options menu, and not the drawer menu.  I was not previously aware there were differences in how they were handled.  I fixed my issue by calling the navigation view, then retrieving the menu from that, which seems to work. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is also looking to fix this problem with the nav_drawer menu, you have to access it differently than the standard options menu (Thanks to Sound Conception for pointing out the difference).  The code should get the menu from the navigation view.

The working code is below, it is the initial menu builder for the app, and it checks to see if the class is a magical class before deciding to show or hide the spellbook option in the nav drawer.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Set<String> setMagical;
    setMagical = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Bard", "Cleric", "Druid", "Paladin",
            "Ranger", "Sorcerer", "Warlock", "Wizard"));
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem spellbook = nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.nav_spellbook);

    if(setMagical.contains(characterClass))
    {

        spellbook.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {
        spellbook.setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```